# GeoExt 2 & Ext 4

Tags: geoext-2, ext-js-4

I just started using GeoExt as well as Ext. I have been trying to get tutorials to get me started with GeoExt 2. I only find tutorials for Geoext 1. I have an error that says "please verify that map.js exists".

Comment: Have you tried looking at the examples/documentation here: https://geoext.github.io/geoext2/

Comment: Thanks for response Jonathan, I started there. There is not much documentation on GeoExt 2. There example are good and what I need but once I get started with mu first page...